# Google chart frozen after click label, how to use 'select' listener in 'ready' listener correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, charts, google-visualization, onclicklistener

I'm using Google Chart to draw a line chart under a Google Map. My goal is when I click a dot on chart will pop a infowindow on map. I have implemented it and it works well except: If I keep clicking the dot on chart, the infowindow on map works fine, but once I click the chart's label(it supposedly will highlight the line correspondingly), everything frozen, I have to refresh whole page. My function to draw:

```
function drawChart(){
    var seriesArr = [];
    var columnsArr = [0];
    var dataTable = genDataTable(seriesArr, columnsArr);    

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType':'LineChart',
            'containerId': 'chart',
            'options':{
                    'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '95%'},
                    'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': -10, 'max': 120}},
                    'legend':{'position': 'top'},
                    'interpolateNulls': true,
                    'series': seriesArr
            },
            'view': {'columns': columnsArr}
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', onReady);
    function onReady() {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'select', popInfoWindow
    }

    function popInfoWindow(){
        chartObject = chart.getChart();
        var ts = Date.parse(dataTable.getValue(chartObject.getSelection()[0].row, 0))/1000;
        //codes here to pop a infowindow on google map, basically is using the dot's timestamp to find lat/lng
    }

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
       'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
       'containerId': 'control',
       'options': {
       'filterColumnIndex': 0,
         'ui': {
           'chartType': 'LineChart',
           'chartOptions': {
            'interpolateNulls': true,
             'chartArea': {'width': '95%'},
             'curveType': 'function',
           },
           'chartView': {
             'columns': columnsArr
           },
         }
       }
    });

    dashboard.bind(control, chart);
    dashboard.draw(dataTable);
}
```

Everything works fine if I don't touch the chart's label. I guess the problem is in:

```
function onReady(){...}
```

In this function I add a 'select' listener to catch my actions on chart's dot, but click label is a kind of 'select' too I guess, so it triggers some conflict?  I can give up the feature of click label to highlight lines but only keep the feature of pop info window on map, how can I turn off the label select listener or avoid the conflict?

Really appreciate for your time and help!

Thanks

Comment: Does your visualization code with event handler work without Google Map API?

Comment: You mean only for the chart? Yes it works, click/hover the label will highlight the lines, and never frozen.

Comment: Never mind...I resolve it by myself...It's because when I click label getSelection() will return a invalid(null) response then break google's api.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the length of the selection in the chart.  The array can be zero elements long (the user deselects a point) or it can contain multiple elements (if the user selects more than one point).  You don't have multiple select enabled in your chart, so simply testing the length of the array is sufficient:

```
function popInfoWindow(){
    chartObject = chart.getChart();
    var selection = chartObject.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
        var ts = Date.parse(dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0))/1000;
        //codes here to pop a infowindow on google map, basically is using the dot's timestamp to find lat/lng
    }
    else {
        // do something if the user deselects a point
    }
}
```

Also, you have a syntax error here:

```
function onReady() {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'select', popInfoWindow()
}
```

The `(` after `popInfoWindow` should be removed, and in the interest of good coding practice, the line should terminate with a `;`:

```
function onReady() {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'select', popInfoWindow);
}
```

Comment: Yah you are right, I write all these functions in one block, I split them here for a better look and copy wrong. And yes I noticed the issue here I should check the length first. Thanks for your time.